Determine EH of the half reaction at equilibrium with Nernst Equation

So here is the problem: When Cl2 gas is added to aqueous solution it rapidly and completely disproportionate to form equal amounts of hypochlorous acid (HOCl) and hydrochloric acid (HCl).
(a) What is the average oxidation state of chlorine in the following compounds?
(b) If 8 mg/L Cl 2(g) is added to an anoxic aqueous solution that is pH buffered at pH 7.0, determine EH of the OCl-/Cl- half reaction at equilibrium if Cl2(g) is the only source of chlorine in the solution and no other redox-active constituents are present.
(c) Determine the concentration of ammonium (NH4+) in redox equilibrium with [NO2-] = 1 μM in the redox-buffered solution described in part (a).
Here is my solution
(a)
Cl in OCl is +1 and Cl in Cl- is -1
(b) 8 mg/L Cl = 8 x 10^-3 g/L / 71 g/mol = 1.1 x 10^-4 M = [Cl-]initial
From the equation: HOCl <-> OCl- + H+
Mass Balance: Ct,Cl = [HOCl] + [OCl-] = 1.1 x 10^-4 M
pH = 7 => [H+] = 10^-7 M
[HOCl] = a0 * Ct,Cl = [H+]/(Ka+[H+]) * 1.1 x 10^-4 = 0.8 x 1.1 x 10^-4 M = 0.9 x 10^-4 M
[OCl-] = 1.1 x 10^-4 - 0.9 x 10^-4 M = 0.2 x 10^-4 M
OCl- + 2H+ + 2e- <-> Cl- + H2O
EH = E0 - RT/nF x ln(Cl-)/(OCl-)
HOCl + H+ + 2e- ⇋ Cl- + H2O     E0H = 1.481 V
EH = 1.046 V
Is there any wrong with my EH value in part (b) and I'm also stuck at part (c).
Please help!
